# Exchange JSAPI token for longlived oauth2 token for REST API

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

Linkedin API uses OAUTH 2.0 for its REST and a different one for its JSAPI services.

This documentation

http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/exchange-jsapi-tokens-rest-api-oauth-tokens

describes how to exchange the JSAPI bearer token for a longer lived OAUTH1.0a token. It works fine, however using OAUTH2 everywhere would be much easier.

---

Is it possible to exchange the JSAPI Bearer token for a longer lived OAUTH2 token to be used with the REST services?

Comment: My understanding is you can not exchange a JS API token for a OAuth2 token at this time.

Comment: Whats the alternative for SPA that need to call internal apis that need to make liked in REST calls if there is no token exchange possible. It seems like this is possible https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2 "Exchange Authorization Code for an Access Token" section, but as it was the jsapi that recieved the oauth token then there is no callback url so nothing I add matched this.,